# Matplotlib x-axis overlap

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have two lists, x_axis which is list of time in the format of '12:30:00'. The y-axis is percent values. I need to plot all the values on a graph, however since x-axis string is too long they overlap. Is there anyway I can have matplotlib not show every single time on x-axis? Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Matplotlib will only show each individual coordinate as tick if the data are strings. Use datetime instead.

Answer (score 19):

You could rotate and print every 2nd ticklabel:

```
_ = plt.plot(df['str_time'], df.Pct, 'ro')
ax = plt.gca()
plt.axis([0,24,0,50])
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
for label in ax.get_xaxis().get_ticklabels()[::2]:
    label.set_visible(False)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can rotate your label to show the list time using the below code.

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this automatically is by using autofmt_xdate

```
fig.autofmt_xdate():
```

for getting fig object you will have to call the subplot functions

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

Works really well

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I needed to step x axis digits instead of rotating.

`ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, max_number, 5)) #step 5 digits`

Output:[image: matplotlib plot]