# The solution for overlapping strings on x axis takes to long to plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

My first problem was overlapping string on the x axis, solved it with following link: 
[Matplotlib x-axis overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033189/matplotlib-x-axis-overlap)

But now it takes 30-45 minutes to plot a graph of one week, or the program crashes.

Fixed my first problem with the link above but can't think of something te reduce the time to plot.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('DB12022019.csv')

#take out the part that I wanne visualize 
dataset = data.loc[50:100,:]
#reverse data for chronological order 
dataset = dataset.reindex(index=dataset.index[::-1])



#Solution based on the link above 
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)

ax = plt.gca()
    for label in ax.get_xaxis().get_ticklabels()[::1]:
    label.set_visible(False)

delta = 10 
    for label in ax.get_xaxis().get_ticklabels()[::delta]:
    label.set_visible(True)

#plot the graph 
plt.plot(dataset.eventTime, dataset.P_HVAC, color = "blue")
plt.xlabel('tijd',fontsize=20)
plt.title('Vermogen [kW] periode 26/12 van 15u tot 16u', fontsize = 20)
plt.ylabel('Vermogen [kW]', fontsize=20)
plt.legend(['P_HVAC'],fontsize=20)
plt.xticks(size = 12)
plt.yticks(size = 20)

plt.show()
```

Problem: takes to long to plot a graph of a longer period. 
Someone a suggestion to reduce the time? Thanks in advance

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: You are adjusting the ticks on a plot you haven't made yet.  Please put the tick adjustment after the plot comment.

Comment: Matplotlib would by default not produce more than about 10 ticks and labels on an axes, unless you plot categorical data where each datum gets its own tick and label. Consider plotting numeric data instead, such that the automatic tickers give you nice tick locations and labels. "chronological order" suggest that one column of your data is date or time. In that case make sure that column is correctly read in as `datetime` or `numpy.datetime64`.